# C#: Why is Application in System.Windows.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net

The `Application` class in `System.Windows.Forms` have a some properties that can be quite useful. For example:

- ProductName
- ProductVersion
- CompanyName
- ExecutablePath
- StartupPath
- CommonAppDataPath
- CommonAppDataRegistry
- UserAppDataPath
- UserAppDataRegistry
- LocalUserAppDataPath

Why are these in in a class in `System.Windows.Forms`? What if I wanted to access the `CommonAppDataPath` in a console application? Would I have to reference *System.Windows.Forms.dll* then, or is there an alternative for console applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from MSDN [System.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.aspx) namespace documentation:

> The System.Windows.Forms namespace contains classes for creating Windows-based applications that take full advantage of the rich user interface features available in the Microsoft Windows operating system.

The only real reason I can see the Application class being placed in the System.Windows.Forms namespace is because it handles Windows Messages which are usually posted by Form controls.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. I guess someone at Microsoft messed up regarding the single responsibility principle or something then... :p

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time either! :P

Answer (score 10):

For the paths, you can also look at the `Environment` class in .NET:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

and there's a whole slew of "special" folders you can ask for.

The CompanyName and other options are pulled from the "AssemblyInfo.cs" in your "Properties" folder by default - if you have such a file, you can also access those yourself in code.

> Hm, with those paths you have to
>   append the company name and product
>   name and such yourself though...

Yes, that's what the System.Windows.Forms assembly is doing for you. If you don't have a Winforms app, you'll have to do that yourself, that's true.

Marc

Comment: +1, sounds good to me, and all the useful stuff is available in any .net application, not limited to winforms

Comment: Hm, with those paths you have to append the company name and product name and such yourself though...

Comment: @Svish: I don't understand what you mean - those are just the default "special folders" that Windows keeps internally - your user's AppData directory or stuff like that.

Comment: For example: When I print out `Application.UserAppDataPath`, I get *C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\CompanyName\ProductName\ProductVersion*. But when I print out Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), I get only *C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming*.

Comment: How would you access the stuff in AssemblyInfo.cs? It has no class... (hehe...)

Comment: That's where System.Windows.Forms gets that information from, that's what I'm saying

Comment: The AssemblyInfo class is in the System.Reflection namespace. You would need to create a new Assembly class and then use the GetCustomAttributes method to retrieve the values.

Comment: @James: Aha, so some reflection is required to get those then.

Comment: @Svish, yup I would imagine the Application class is simply wrapping this up in the static properties.

Answer (score 2):

Information such as "ProductName" comes from the main assembly in a WinForms application.  There is no "main" assembly in an ASP.NET application.

If you are running under a service account without a profile (which may often be the case for an ASP.NET app), there will be no UserAppDataPath - in fact attempting to dereference the UserAppDataPath property will throw an exception.

For these reasons, it would not make sense to expose this information to an ASP.NET app.

Comment: Good points. Didn't think about the ASP.NET side of things :)

Answer (score 0):

Application class launches win32 message loop which is tightly related to windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the info you're looking for using the Assembly namespace